# EntryPointNotFoundException: Entry point was not found

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, wcf, sitecore

I'm in the process of moving a few .net 4.5 projects to a solution targeting 4.7.2.

The solution is Sitecore 9 based and uses Sitecore/MS Dependency Injection.

Things were going well until one of the projects had a dependency on which I am not migrating across.
This dependency is a WCF project targeting .net 4.5 and using structure mapper as its IOC.

I've attempted to register the dependency (service) in my solution as per below which seemed to get me a bit further but I've hit a wall with an 'Entry point was not found' error and **I'm unsure If its possible to play nice with this dependency without making any changes to it**.

[Entry point was not found error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGc71.png)

**Theory on reason for error:** The log4net dll version is 2.0.1 in all the  projects in my solution, where as the version in the dependency is 2.0.3. Could this be why?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Method in my solution that calls a method in the dependency**

```
public FundDetail GetFundDetail(int fundId)
        {
            FundDetail detail = null;
            var fundIds = new List<int> { fundId };

            var fundDetailParams = new FundDetailsParams
            {
                FundIds = fundIds,
            };

            var fundDetailData = _fundServiceAgent.GetFundDetails(fundDetailParams);

            if (fundDetailData.FundDetails.Any())
            {
                var data = fundDetailData.FundDetails[0];

                detail = new FundDetail
                {
                    APIR = data.APIR,
                    FundId = data.FundId,
                    FundName = data.FundName,
                    DistributionFrequency = data.DistributionFrequency,
                    InceptionDate = data.InceptionDate,
                    MinimumInitialInvestment = data.MinimumInitialInvestment
                };
            }

            return detail;
        }
```

**Registering the services in the dependency in my solution**

```
public class RegisterDependencies : IServicesConfigurator
    {
        public void Configure(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
        {
            serviceCollection.AddTransient(typeof(IFundServiceAgent), typeof(FundServiceAgent));
            serviceCollection.AddTransient(typeof(IServiceClientFactory<IFundService>), ctx => GetServiceClientFactory<IFundService>(ctx.GetService<IFundServiceAgentConfig>()));
            serviceCollection.AddTransient(typeof(IServiceClientFactory<IDistributionService>), ctx => GetServiceClientFactory<IDistributionService>(ctx.GetService<IFundServiceAgentConfig>()));            
        }

        private IServiceClientFactory<T> GetServiceClientFactory<T>(IFundServiceAgentConfig serviceConfig)
        {

            var binding = new NetTcpBinding
            {
                Security = new NetTcpSecurity { Mode = SecurityMode.None },
                MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647,
                MaxBufferSize = 2147483647,
                MaxBufferPoolSize = 2147483647,
                MaxConnections = 100,
            };

            EndpointAddress endPoint;

            switch ((typeof(T).Name))
            {
                case "IFundService":
                    endPoint = new EndpointAddress(serviceConfig.FundServiceUrl);
                    break;
                case "IDistributionService":
                    endPoint = new EndpointAddress(serviceConfig.DistributionServiceUrl);
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new ApplicationException("The type is not supported.");
            }

            return new NoConfigServiceClientFactory<T>(binding, endPoint);
        }
    }
```

**The Service in the dependency (I'm not migrating this across)**

```
public class FundServiceAgent : IFundServiceAgent
    {
        private readonly ILog _logger;
        private readonly IServiceClientFactory<IFundService> _fundServiceClientFactory;
        private readonly IServiceClientFactory<IDistributionService> _distributionServiceClientFactory;

        public FundServiceAgent(IServiceClientFactory<IFundService> fundServiceClientFactory, IServiceClientFactory<IDistributionService> distributionServiceClientFactory)
        {
            _fundServiceClientFactory = fundServiceClientFactory;
            _distributionServiceClientFactory = distributionServiceClientFactory;
            _logger = LogManager.GetLogger(GetType());
        }

        public FundDetailsResult GetFundDetails(FundDetailsParams fundDetailsParams)
        {

            using (_logger.InfoProfiledBlock("GetFundDetails"))
            {
                FundDetailsResult fundDetailsResult;

                _logger.InfoFormat("fundDetailsParams FundIds:[{0}]", string.Join(",", fundDetailsParams.FundIds));

                using (var fundServiceClient = _fundServiceClientFactory.Create())
                {
                    fundDetailsResult = _logger.InfoCall(fundServiceClient.Channel.GetFundDetails, fundDetailsParams);

                }
                _logger.InfoFormat("fundDetailsResult.FundDetails FundIds:[{0}]", string.Join(",", fundDetailsResult.FundDetails.Select(fd => fd.FundId)));

                return fundDetailsResult;
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: You can check whether the dependency in your WCF program is consistent with the version referenced in your other programs. You can see the version in the properties options.

Comment: Thanks @TheobaldDu I can see the log4net versions are different

The log4net dll version is 2.0.1 in all the projects in my solution, where as the version in the dependency is 2.0.3.

Could that cause an Entry point was not found exception?

Comment: This error is usually caused by a mismatch in the referenced collection version, but other errors cannot be ruled out. You can try to replace it with a consistent version to see if the problem can be resolved.